# Como arredondar valor criado em pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Olá
Por favor, em pandas Python 3 estou criando este dataframe com a soma de outro conjunto de dados:

```
total = cand_doacoes.groupby(['CPF_candidato', 'Nome_candidato', 'Cargo']).Valor.sum().reset_index()

total = total[(total['Cargo'] == 'Deputado Federal')]

total.info()
```

> ```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> Int64Index: 5516 entries, 0 to 19707
> Data columns (total 4 columns):
> CPF_candidato     5516 non-null int64
> Nome_candidato    5516 non-null object
> Cargo             5516 non-null object
> Valor             5516 non-null object
> dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
> memory usage: 150.8+ KB
> ```

A coluna Valor eu desejo arredondar para duas casas decimais, então coloquei esse comando:

```
total.round({'Valor': 2})
```

Mas não deu certo:

> ```
> CPF_candidato Nome_candidato  Cargo   Valor
> 0 1608657 STEFANO AGUIAR DOS SANTOS   Deputado Federal    10000,00548,501675,00500,00400,003750,0010000,...
> 1 2498316 HENRIQUE EDUARDO BARROSO MOREIRA    Deputado Federal    240,00124,0025,8699,79285,71245,00
> 6 7331304 CARLOS MAURO CABRAL BENEVIDES   Deputado Federal    3501,4010000,00100000,00200000,00100000,003000...
> ```

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Você tentou fazer `total = total.round({'Valor': 2})`? Outra coisa: estou confuso com os valores exemplificados... era pra ser um valor só? a vírgula é um separador de decimal ou separador de valores em uma lista?

Comment: Obrigado. Sim, tentei o comando inteiro. Mas você tem razão, ele está colocando vírgula onde não devia. 
O Valor original vem de cand_doacoes: 
Valor                             427489 non-null object
Tentei então converter para float64: 
cand_doacoes['Valor'] = cand_doacoes.Valor.astype('float64')
Mas deu erro: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '337,5'
Devo fazer outro tipo de conversão?

Comment: Será que o problema não é o uso da vírgula no lugar do ponto para separador decimal? Tentou com os valores como "337.5"?

Comment: Obrigado, não tentei. Por favor, em pandas como converto uma coluna com vírgulas para ponto? ex: 337,5 -> 337.5

Comment: É mais fácil fazer isso diretamente na leitura do CSV ([ajuda aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31700780/2896619)). Mas também dá pra fazer isso depois convertendo pra string, trocando a vírgula por ponto, e convertendo de volta pra número ([ajuda aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083822/2896619)). Se funcionar, sugiro que você mesmo poste uma resposta com a solução.

Comment: Obrigado, coloquei acima

Comment: Legal que funcionou! Mas não era pra editar a pergunta e colocar nela. Era pra usar o campo de resposta! :) Leia [answer], vai te ajudar a entender como o site funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESPOSTA QUE FUNCIONOU, DO LUIZ VIEIRA - já ao ler o CSV você indica que o decimal é com ",":

```
cand_doacoes = pd.read_csv("doacoes_csv.csv",sep=';',encoding = 'latin_1', decimal = ",")
```

E depois o groupby deu certo:

```
total = eleitos_d_doadores.groupby(['CPF_candidato', 'Nome_urna', 'Cargo_x']).Valor.sum().reset_index()
```